# CONVERT bigint to Varbinary in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running below SQL commands and comparing results with calculator DEC to HEX output.

```
select CONVERT(VARBINARY(2),65280);
```

It gives me **0xFF00** which is right in Calculator.
But when I execute below command:

```
select CONVERT(VARBINARY(6),894811944210);
```

It gives me **0x0C00000112B5** but when I check it on calculator the Result should be 0x00D056F2B512.

Is there anything I am doing incorrect?

Actually, I want to store the MAC Address in Table. for that I have created column with varbinary(250) datatype.
So I am using below line in Insert Statement and while select command I am getting this output - 0x0C00000112B5

```
CONVERT(VARBINARY(6),894811944210)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not just store the mac address in an `int` if that's what you have? They all represent the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking that. As Saving it in VarBinary column will increase the complexity. So I think I have to make datatype of MAC ID column to BIGINT then. It is OK. right?

Comment: Apparently a mac id is 6 bytes. An `int` only stores 4 bytes. `bigint` stores 8 so yes it should be `bigint`. Are you receiving this data as a number? How does it need to be represented when reporting?

Comment: Actually, I am receiving data in HEX, but while saving I will convert it in BigInt and While fetching I will convert it back in HEX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MS Docs int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Bigint Data type    - 8 Bytes

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8),CAST(894811944210 AS BIGINT));
SELECT CAST(0x000000D056F2B512 AS BIGINT)

0x000000D056F2B512

894811944210
```